# How do I select an svg element from within given node in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How do I get the value of an attribute of the svg created thusly?

```
// SVG setup
var svg  = d3.select(vizNode).append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .style('background', 'white')
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

// Text
svg.append('text')
    .datum(newValue)
    .attr('class', 'meter-center-text')
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('fill', mainColor)
    .text(function(d){
        return parseFloat(newValue);
    });
console.log("Done update");
```

I want to get the datum value back from the text (because I'm going to increment it).

I assumed I wanted something a bit like

```
previousValue = d3.select(vizNode).select('svg').select('text').attr('darum');
```

but that returns nothing.  Indeed

```
previousValue = d3.select(vizNode).select('svg');
```

returns nothing, so I must be on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to get data back is `selection.datum()`, not `selection.attr('darum')`. Also i assume `darum` is a typo.

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rovj8164/

```
var value = d3.select('div').select('svg').select('text').datum();
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just spent sooo long wondering why that worked in the fiddle but not in my code before I remembered that on the first iteration of the loop the svg didn't exist yet!  Doesn't come more schoolboy than that :P